# How to make authorization in Drupal using another site/system/database?

Tags: drupal-7, authorization

Is it possible authorize users in Drupal(7) using other site? I have non-drupal community and I want keep and manage logins/passwords there. But also I've got public site on Drupal and I would like that users from non-drupal site can login using existing logins/passwords. May be there are some natural way (like OpenId)? I can arrange any kind af data export/import/verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this in Drupal. For starters, there are several contrib modules that'll allow you to use OpenID and other providers for authentication

1. http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector/
2. http://drupal.org/project/rpx (Janrain)
3. http://drupal.org/project/oauthconnector (Oauth)

etc.

An hour-long-dedicated search on Drupal.org will give you several alternatives to choose from.

Besides that, there are also contrib modules for authenticating from several other platforms ranging from the popular to the obscure. For example,

1. http://drupal.org/project/gigya
2. http://drupal.org/project/cs_social_networks (Czech and Slovak social networks)
3. http://drupal.org/project/phpbb

Take your pick!

Comment: Thank you avadhutp, one thing left is to find out how to set up my non-drupal site for proper account export.

Comment: Is your non-Drupal site deployed in a standard/popular framework/CMS? If so, it should be pretty easy to find the instructions online?

Otherwise, you could use a simple PHP script [like this one](http://drupal.org/node/311442) and modify it to your liking. Look at the section regarding migrating users.